# experiment of tossing a coin repeatedly until the outcomes of two consecutive tosses are same.

Tags: probability

Consider an experiment of tossing a coin repeatedly until the outcomes of two consecutive tosses are same. If the probability of a random toss resulting in head is 1/3, then the probability that the
experiment stops with head is

Comment: Hi, since you are new, please note that on this forum, you must first tell us what you have tried, and where you are stuck. Proper help will only then be provided.

Comment: I was stuck in which direction should I proceed as only little information is given 

Comment: P(head) $= 1/3$, so P(tail) = $2/3$. Isn't that enough information ? By the way, is this from a book/assignment, or have you made up the problem yourself ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be modelled with a Markov Chain with 5 states: $S$, $H$, $T$, $W$ and $L$, where $S$ is the starting state, $H, L$ are when the last toss has been head or tails respectively but the game is still running and $W, L$ are when the game ends with a head (we "win") or a tail (we "lose").

With $P(W|X)$ we denote the probability of winning if we are currently in the state $X$. We want to know $P(W | S)$. We have:

$$
P(W | S) = \frac{1}{3} P(W|H) + \frac{2}{3} P(W|T) ,
$$

$$
P(W|H) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} P(W|T)
$$
and finally:
$$
P(W|T) = \frac{1}{3} P(W|H).
$$

Given the above, you can get to your desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

P(H)=1/3

P(T)=2/3

We need to find the Probability of
P(HH, THH, HTHH, THTHH......)

We can write it as
P(HH, HTHH, HTHTHH....)+ P(THH, THTHH, THTHTHH....)

By putting the values of Probability of H and T we will get a G.P and by finding the sum of it we will get the answer

And the answer is 5/21